# Link release artifacts on a github page (private repo)

Tags: github-pages

Is it possible to publish a link to a release-artifact on a "github pages" page? This is easy like:

https://github.com/rocket-monkey/my-app/releases/download/v0.0.1/my-app.io-0.0.1.dmg

But, what it it's a private repository?

Comment: your link doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to to dedicate a public empty repository, in which you create dummy commits, one per release, with tags representing your "release", and where you can re-upload your artifacts initially published in your private repository.

That way, you can point interested parties to the public repository artifact release, instead of the private one.

Comment: I think about to move all the core parts of my app (it's a commercial project where i try to make money somewhere in the future) into privately published npm packages.... only the CI server would have access to install all of them... afterwards i'm able to make the whole repository public. I like it more to have everything in one place...

Comment: @jebbie " I like it more to have everything in one place...": i fully understand. But in the meantime, having two explicit referentials, one for private data, one for public, is safer and guarantees that there won't be any mistake.